# C++ Qt application on Android and iOS

Tags: android, c++, ios, qt, portability

As an experiment, I have a pure Qt C++ application (without QML) compiling (with cmake & ninja) and running on:

- Windows
- macOS
- Linux (ubuntu and centos/redhat)
- FreeBSD

It uses basically QMainWindow, QGraphicsItem and QDialog, iostream and a few C++ containers and iterators.

I am wondering if the port to Android is:

- possible
- easy or complex (if possible)
- and if there are examples online

The same with iOS.

Comment: The port shouldn't be hard, for a really usable mobile app you'll want to do a separate UI layer using QtQuick though. I also at least in the past, using QMake was easier when developing for iOS/Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I have worked in many Qt apps developed for iOS and Android. However,  never used cmake, but qmake. it is good that you started experimenting using cmake which is the future as qmake is going to be deprecated sometime in the future. Qt's official documentation started adding cmake getting started tutorial.

> https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html

I would like to suggest to use Qt Quick for GUI on mobile devices.

Comment: Didn't start the iOS port yet, but I moved back to qmake because the android manifest support in cmake is still very weak.  Everything goes well for android with cmake until I need to work with the manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it's possible:
It's easy to compile C++-Qt applications for both Android and iOS.
For iOS, you'll still need a Mac with Xcode.
Deploying, debugging, and running the app is quite simple and seamless, too.

Practically, it's a horrible idea to try to port the GUI of a non-trivial desktop-application to mobile.
Graphical user interfaces designed to be used with a large screen, mouse and keyboard just don't work well on small touch screens.

Since you've mentioned `QDialog`: Some concepts work very differently on mobile compared to desktop.
E.g., *Dialog* is replaced by *Activity* and users usually don't deal with files.

You can (I've done it), however, design a Qt GUI-application without any QML, that works well on small touch screens and is at least usable on desktop.
It requires a lot of manual tweaking and hacking, but It's possible.

Notes:

- `qmake` is easier than `cmake` for mobile apps (that should change in future)
- although Qt has some abstractions, you'll probably need some platform-specific code (i.e., `JNI`, snippets of `Java` and `Objective-C` and many `#ifdef`s)

Comment: I agree at a billion percents that it is an horrible idea. It is just for an experiment, an exercise to get the feeling on how the compilation process work.  Then this could be a starting point to further and much cleaner explorations.

Comment: For a simple example, you won't need Java nor Objective-C code. That's only a problem when you're starting to do more "advanced" stuff like opening a file or sending notifications.

Comment: I agree now as well with your note about qmake and cmake. The latter was simply a nightmare when it came to introduce the android manifest, so I moved back to qmake, which is a pity.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at Qt to Android: https://youtu.be/AQOU7XvXyBQ

Dynamic Qt widgets you can add with dynamic sizing: https://youtu.be/20mjSqJ_ygM